# Why isn't my CSS being rendered?

Tags: html, css

Here is the content of my webpage:

```
  1 <html>
  2 <head>
  3     <link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" media="all">
  4 </head>
  5 <body>
  6 <a href="link4">Link4</a>
  7 <br>
  8 <a href="link3">Link3</a>
  9 <br>
 10 <a href="link2">Link2</a>
 11 <br>
 12 <a href="link1">Link1</a>
 13 </body>
 14 </html>
```

Here is my CSS file:

```
  1 body {
  2     background-color:#000000;
  3 }
```

What am I doing wrong? I just want an external stylesheet that makes the background black

Comment: You probably are not calling it in the correct directory or something. In your code above, the css file would be in the same directory as the html file.

Comment: It is in the same directory as index.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have a typo it looks like.

```
<link ref="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" media="all">
```

Should be

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" media="all">
```

Notice the change from `ref` to `rel`